# SQL Server Backup Device file size

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2012, restore

After reading Pinal Dave's useful article on [restoring databases](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/14/sql-server-backup-timeline-and-understanding-of-database-restore-process-in-full-recovery-model/) I am planning to utilise the following setup...

1. My 400mb database is in D:\databases\
2. Recovery model is Full
3. Create a backup device in C:\dbbackups
4. Every day a Full backup will be run on the database to the backup file on C:
5. Every 4 hours a transactional log backup will be run on the database to the backup file on C:
6. Every 24 hours the server host takes a differential file backup of C: & D: which I expect will copy the SQL database and backup device files in their entirety
7. Every 24 hours the server host takes a SQL backup of the database files
8. Every week I download the backup device file to our office off-site

I know I could probably improve on that (pointers welcome!) but cost is always the factor, so I'm trying to limit risk as much as I can.  In addition to the above pointers...

- Taking into account steps 1-5 above, does that mean that the backup file will simply grow and grow forever as the new backups are performed?
- Am I correct in thinking that I only need one Full backup plus the following log backups in order to restore to the latest 4 hour backup taken?
- If so, is it possible to have the backups overwritten on say a three week retention period?  If not, how do other DBA's limit these file sizes?

Desperately trying to avoid becoming the next disaster story... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't certain about the options used in your backup scripts, one tool you may want to research is [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance script](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). Even though it's a suite of tools, you can look (and use) just the backup portion alone if you'd like. I'm recommending it because it takes into account many of the concerns you're having about running out of space and other best practices.

One note I'd like to make for points 3 to 5, is that if possible, do *not* backup directly to your C: drive. Remember: it hosts Windows. If it runs out of room, your server will crash. If your only drive options are C: and D:, then backup to the D: drive. A better solution would be to add another disk. It's for this same reason that we don't want to host our database files on the C: drive either.

Another thing you may want to consider is moving the backups to networked storage (upon completion) while waiting to move them off-site. If your server crashes, you'll still have access to them from the network store, and you may not need to recall the week-old backups from off-site. I do suggest to continue to send copies off-site as well.

As for a rotation scheme for your backups, it should be based on whatever SLA (service level agreement) that you have set with the users you are supporting, balanced by the resources you have available. There isn't any "right" answer so much as needing to find the answer that works for your situation, and that you and your users are comfortable with. That said, be sure to restore your backups and test them before adding them to your long-term rotation.

As for your question about full/log backups, that is correct. Each log backup will rely upon a full backup as a base. So in the case of F1 --> L1 --> L2 --> L3 --> L4 --> F2 --> L5 --> L6 --> L7 --> L8... if you'd like to restore to L3, you'd need backups F1, L1, L2, and L3, in that order. If you'd like to restore to your second full backup, you'd just need F2.

Finally, if you need more help, definitely Google for SQL Server backups. There's a ton of great resources available from bloggers. And of course there's this site and [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) for questions specific to DBAs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.  I'm actually creating the backup scripts myself, and the drives are new, so there's no concern about space at the moment, just effective use of it moving forwards.  I take your point about backing up to C: which is wise, however, this was just an extra measure given network backup occurs automatically as well.

Comment: Thanks also for clarifying point 2 about the latest Full backup.  We've successfully restored and tested backups, so that's great so far.  My points were mainly - HOW can we achieve a rotational backup that overwrites earlier backups?  Can this actually be done, or do I need to create a new backup device file every month or so, and swap to that and download the previous one, thus creating a library of backed-up-backup devices?!?  I spent all day yesterday reading about backups but couldn't find clarification on this particular point!

Comment: Well, to be honest, I've not used logical backup devices in the past. I've always simply used the file path. But what you may be able to do is include an update script that runs before your backup - [it can update the location of the logical backup device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179313.aspx#LogicalBackupDevice). You could do this to rotate between a number of files, or you could instead choose to use the regular filepath way of coding backup scripts.

Comment: As for historical rotation, you might think about keeping backups available for a __ week period, and tag those that you've tested for longer-term/deep storage. __ weeks and "deep storage" would be periods defined by your SLA - again based on comfort level and resources that you have. A common scheme is the [grandfather-father-son](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme#Grandfather-father-son) rotation. It's originally based on tape backups, but works equally well for files.

Comment: I am currently backing up to a file on a drive, not a drive (such as tape drive per-se).  So, do you think I could script backups to create a monthly backup file (e.g. 2013-03.bak) then use that if the month is March?  Then come April, download the 2013-03.bak from the server leaving 2013-04.bak to do its thing?

Comment: Using the backups you are keeping now, you really just need an organizational system to know which ones have been tested and which you have promoted to grandfather/father/monthly status. This system might be a database, an excel file, a powershell script with a log file... whatever is easiest for you to maintain and find the  information you need. If you wanted to with logical backup devices, you could definitely script a special one for monthly backups, then connect the logical name to a new filepath each time.

Comment: Great.  My T-Sql searching starts today!  Thanks for your help!